# Can't display a Zend Form in my .phtml file

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I'm working on a small php application using Zend Framework. I created a form using `Zend_Form` but when I try to display it in the browser, it's not working properly.

Here is my Form class:

```
class IndexForm extends Zend_Form {

public function init(){

    $this->setAction('main/main');
    $this->setMethod('post');
    $username = $this->addElement('text','uname',array('filters'=>array('StringTrim','StringToLower'),
             'validators'=>array('Alpha',
                array('StringLength',false,array(3,20)),
            ),
            'required'=>true,
            'label'=>'User Name:'));

    $password = $this->addElement('password','pwd',array('filters'=>array('StringTrim'),
            'validtors'=>array('Alnum',
            array('StringLength',false,array(6,20)),),
            'required'=>true,
            'label'=>'Password:'
            ));

    $login = $this->addElement('submit', 'login', array(
            'required' => false,
            'ignore'   => true,
            'label'    => 'Login',
    )); 
    }
}

?>
```

Here is my IndexController.php

```
<?php

class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

public function init() {
    /*
     * Initialize action controller here
     */
}

public function indexAction() {
    include APPLICATION_PATH.'/models/Forms/IndexForm.php';
    $form = new IndexForm();
    $this->view->form = $form;
}

}
```

Here is my `index.phtml`, where I need to display the form.

```
<html>
<style>
</style>

<body><br>
<img alt="" src="http://localhost/Accounts/application/views/scripts/images/logo.png" width=200px height=80px><!-- see whether you can get the host name dynamically -->
<div id="text" >
<h1>Welcome</h1><br><hr>
<h4>Please Log in To View The Main Page</h4></div>

<?=$this->form?> <!--here I want to display the form-->

<div><?php include APPLICATION_PATH.'/views/scripts/layouts/footer.php';?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The output I get instead of the form is `form?>`.

Why is this? what's wrong in my codes? Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Charu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Try

```
 <?php echo $this->form ?>
```

If this works, then you have short tags disabled. Enable it using

```
short_open_tag = 1;
```

Comment: Don' use `<?`. Prefer `<?php`.

Comment: thanks for your reply Somesh. `short_open_tag` has been set to `1`.
I also tried `<? echo $this->form ?>`. Still it's not working.. :(

then I used `<?php echo $this->form?>`, then, the form is displayed with a notice ` Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\Accounts\library\Zend\View\Helper\HtmlElement.php `+ a table as a usual `php` error.

Comment: I think my `php.ini` is still not configured properly. But `short_open_tag` is set to `1`!!

Comment: `<? echo $this->form ?>` is still a short open tag

Comment: thanks a lot guys, finally I made it work. It had occurred because of the validator I have used in the `password` field. Don't know why, but now it is working properly.. thanks again :-)

Comment: wow, we all missed that one. Also, you don't have to include the form file everywhere. As long as you properly name the form, Zend can autoload it. Try naming it Application_Form_IndexForm or use Zend's CLI tool to create forms and controllers etc. No more including will be needed

Answer (score 2):

Check php.ini for

```
short_open_tag = 1;
```

And see http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: thanks for your reply. `short_open_tag` has been set to `1`. But, it's not working...

Comment: are you sure? Should work then. To be sure, try to output this
`<pre><?php echo ini_get('short_open_tag');?></pre>`
right before form output.

Comment: `<pre><?php echo ini_get('short_open_tag');?></pre>` gave the output `1` and that means `short_open_tag` works, isn't it? I have fixed the problem mate. It was with the validator I have used in `password` field. Thanks a lot :-)